# "The mysqli extension is missing" Tried everything but still no fix!

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I recently upgraded to php 8.2.7. Everything was fine until I checked phpmyadmin and got the **mysqli extention is missing**. I edited the php.ini file in `/etc/php/8.2/apache2` directory and added the `extension=mysqli.so` and restarted apache2 and mariadb. It didn't work! Then I added the full path as mentioned in the php.ini file: `extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/mysqli.so` and restarted. It still didn't work.

I tried a lot of solution including upgrading phpmyadmin to 5.2.1 manually. It's not working and keeps showing the same error.

`php -m` gives me the following output

```
[PHP Modules]

bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
random
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend
OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules] 

Zend OPcache
```

As you can see I have `mysqli` module but it won't load for some reason. Can anyone provide me a solution

I am using linux mint 20.3

Comment: The output of `php -m` shows you the command line interface, which has a different configuration file from the Apache module. You should look at the output of `<?php phpinfo();` in your browser for details about that configuration. How was your old PHP installed (did you compile it yourself, use a package manager, etc) and how did you perform the upgrade?

Comment: @ibennetch My previous version of php was installed via linux mint's repository but I was only able to upgrade to latest version after adding the ondrej/php repository.